# Issue with SQL join query

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, inner-join

this is a simplified version of my query. It runs in SQLite without an issue, but not so in MYSQL.

**Error**: Unknown column 'tab2.key' in 'on clause'

```
SELECT 
  tab2.key AS remarksId, 
  tab1.sessionDate AS date, 
  tab1.sessionStart AS startTime
FROM 
  table1 AS tab1, 
  table2 AS tab2, 
  table3 AS tab3, 
  table4 AS tab4
INNER JOIN 
  table5 AS tab5 
  ON 
    tab5.remarkId = tab2.key 
  WHERE 
    tab1.userId='<anyNumber>' AND 
    tab2.objectiveId='<anyKey>' AND 
    tab1.reportId=tab2.reportId AND 
    tab1.reportId=tab3.key AND 
    tab4.key=tab3.sortieId 
ORDER BY date, startTime;
```

To put the columns in ` unfortunately was no help.

I'm not sure if naming a column 'key' is a good practice ([MYSQL Keywords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html)), but I have to handle this somehow, due to existing installations. For a quick test, I renamed the 'key'-columns, but also without any success.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Don't mix join notations.  The engine can handle the ANSI 89 or the ANSI 92 not both.  I'd recommend changing your , join notation to use inner join notation.

Comment: Why are you mixing join types?  You should only use `JOIN` syntax with INNER, LEFT, RIGHT, etc.  Why are you using old-style comma separated joins?

Comment: why are you making an alias for tab2.key (as remarksId) then not using it in the join at all?

Comment: Stupid remark maybe... But are you executing that SQL on the right schema?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply put, **Don't mix join notations**, and if given the choice use the current ANSI 92 join syntax instead of the 89 standard (yes... that's 1992 and 1989!)

Secondly... aliases are to help you save typing and handle multiple references to the same table.... so... simplify the names t1, t2, t3...

Lastly... if you have to use reserved/restricted words in mySQL use backticks.

```
SELECT t2.`key` AS remarksId 
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
   ON t1.reportId = t2.reportId 
INNER JOIN table3 t3
   ON t1.reportId = t3.`key`  
INNER JOIN table4 t4
   ON t4.`key` = t3.sortieId 
INNER JOIN table5 t5
   ON t5.remarkId = t2.`key`
WHERE t1.userId = '<anyNumber>' 
  AND t2.objectiveId = '<anyKey>'  
ORDER BY `date`, startTime;
```

Comment: you beat me to it!

Comment: @da-chiller Comma means cross join. It is *current* syntax. But it doesn't bind as tightly as explicit joins. There are stylistic arguments against comma (including other people suffering from misconceptions) but "don't mix" arguments are specious. (Prior to  5.0.12 MySQL did not implement lower precedence.)